# Where to buy Raspberry pi a+?

Tags: pi-a+

Just what the title says, where can I still buy an RPI a+ thats not a rip-off? It exactly meets my needs for my project!

Comment: That would depend on where in the world you are.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off topic per the FAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just on [DigiKey's](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/programmers-development-systems/evaluation-boards-embedded-mcu-dsp/2621773?k=raspberry%20pi&WT.srch=1&gclid=Cj0KEQjwl-e4BRCwqeWkv8TWqOoBEiQAMocbP9BY2G4aQANtrR9XrMb4ICmO3vPZZL8dgJ_R5YlSG4caAsZ48P8HAQ)website, and they have the A+ for ~$30. I don't know how that compares with other pricing, but they're a reputable supplier.

Comment: Ohh thanks! One more question: does it ship to Canada and what is the price in CAD?

Comment: Looks like they do CAD 42.73, apparently - http://www.digikey.ca/product-search/en/programmers-development-systems/evaluation-boards-embedded-mcu-dsp/2621773?k=raspberry%20pi%20a%2B